# Adding LegendItems in Flex places horizontally not vertically (as it's supposed to)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, uicomponents, legend

I'm dynamically inserting LegendItems into a Legend using the following code:

```
signalLegend.removeAllChildren();
signalLegend.direction = "vertical";
for (var i:int = 0; i < numItems - 1; i++) {
    signalLegend.addChild(new LegendItem());
    legendItem = signalLegend.getChildAt(i) as LegendItem;
    legendItem.label = "Title here";
    legendItem.setStyle("fill", theColour);
}
```

While the Legend direction is set as vertical, all the items are appearing horizontally.

Very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

use the labelPlacement style

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug. The children of the Legend control are placed wrong, if you add them at runtime.
Set the direction to "horizontal" and the items will appear vertically. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution.

```
                <mx:Legend id="nhLeg"
                       updateComplete="LegendPosition()"
                       direction="vertical"
                       width="80%"/>
```

And then in the LegendPosition() function:

```
            private function LegendPosition():void
        {

            nhLeg.direction="vertical";
        }
```